# Usage of 'local' plugin in coredns

Tags: kubernetes, coredns, kube-dns, unbound

As I am new to coredns configurations in kubernetes and I'm trying to explore plugins provided by coredns in kubernetes. I see a plugin named [local](https://coredns.io/plugins/local/) which will respond with a reply to local requests. But I could not understand a use-case where this plugin will be exactly useful for. Can someone explain with an example how it can be make use of?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the `local` plugin for CoreDNS [explains](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/4260#issue-736755779), `localhost.<searchpath>` queries are hitting coredns, which is wrong. So, he wrote this plugin to intercept localhost.<'domain'> queries and return the correct response.

From the [official CoreDNS github web page](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/tree/master/plugin/local):

> `local` will respond with a basic reply to a "local request". Local request are defined to be names in the following zones: localhost, 0.in-addr.arpa, 127.in-addr.arpa and 255.in-addr.arpa and any query asking for `localhost.<domain>`.

**With local enabled any query falling under these zones will get a reply. This prevents the query from "escaping" to the internet and putting strain on external infrastructure.**

You can check the code of the `local` plugin [here](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/local/local.go). I don't see similar to the unbound local-zone nodefault functionality there.

See all in-tree plugins for CoreDNS [here](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/tree/master/plugin).